# How to perform an Angularjs file upload?

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

i'm trying to upload a file but i'm getting an error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Please help me, here is all the code in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XvT2GUNOkgbxoHlx6VYz?p=preview)

```
    myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
        $scope.uploadFile = function(){
            var file = $scope.myFile;
            console.log('file is ' );
            console.dir(file);
            var uploadUrl = "http://10.10.10.50:8080/upload";
            fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: First check your uploadUrl is ready to accept this file. That should be a url issue.

Comment: See this plunker, I have modified the `uploadUrl` https://plnkr.co/edit/Eej3Xibrna3xghzDH548?p=preview

Comment: yes it was an url problem, it was a problem from my spring application... thank you guys.